# Selenium SelectWindow Command not working

Tags: selenium

Selenium Select Window command fails and shows "Could not find window with title....". but if i Execute the Select Window command alone it passes the case and verifying the elements.

Code i used:

```
public void testDefaultlogo() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("http://Sitename/samp.aspx");
    selenium.type("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_txt_LoginName", "uname");
    selenium.type("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_txt_Password", "pwd@12");
    selenium.click("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_btn_login");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
    selenium.click("ctl00_defaultLogo");
    selenium.selectWindow("Sample~Window-ID");
    verifyEquals("http://Sitename/index.html", selenium.getLocation());
    selenium.close();
    selenium.selectWindow ("null");
    verifyTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("ctl00_defaultLogo"));
```

I mean by clicking one by one of the follwing commands in Selenium IDE it shows green but if i run the case it failed and shows as i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

What I can get from your code is that, clicking the "ctl00_defaultLogo" will popup another window. The possible issue could be that after write the command `selenium.click("ctl00_defaultLogo")` you need to wait for the popup to load.

The possible resolution, insert the command

```
selenium.WaitForPopUp("Sample~Window-ID", "5000");
```

before the

```
selenium.selectWindow("Sample~Window-ID");
```

This will cause selenium to wait for 5 secs before selecting the popup window.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

some times it may not work for that u better use.

```
open_window("URL","WindowID or title or name");
selenium.selectWindow("WindowID or title or name");
```